# Parsear fecha con libreria momentjs

Tags: javascript, date

Quiero parsear la fecha asi (dia: mes: año "espaciado"  hora: minuto: segundo)

Hice la prueba con `2018-12-10T10:33:57-04:00` y me retorna `12/10/2018  10:12:00`
ese resultado esta mal, yo necesito `10/12/2018  10:33:57`

```js
let fecha = '2018-12-10T10:33:57-04:00'
console.log(moment(fecha).format('MM/DD/YYYY  HH:MM:SS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

otro ejemplo con otra fecha, el minuto siempre sale 12

```js
let fecha2='2018-12-12T18:09:17-04:00';
console.log(moment(fecha2).format('MM/DD/YYYY  HH:MM:SS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @shadow pero el minuto esta mal, sale 10:12 debe ser 10:33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El formato de minuto y segundo debe ser en minúscula.

```js
let fecha = '2018-12-10T10:33:57-04:00'
console.log(moment(fecha).format('MM/DD/YYYY  HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```